# Did Wordpress theme description being indexed by google or shown anywhere

Tags: wordpress, indexing

I wanted to know did Wordpress theme description written in main Style.css file being indexed by Google or shown anywhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The theme description has no effect on your search engine optimisation and it doesnt get displayed anywhere by google results.

Anyone who views your site source code including Google can view your WordPress `style.css` which contains the description. Although it should be noted you can create a WordPress theme which doesn't load the root `style.css` on the front end at all.

Google does index `css` files but it uses this for other purposes like assessing mobile friendliness. It would ignore comments in the `css` which is where the theme description is.

Comment: So that theme description will not be shown or indexed somewhere @James Jones?

Comment: @Anahit DEV theme description is indexed but not not used or shown by Google

Comment: if it will be indexed it should be proper description, right? I created a custom theme so i wanted to setup all properly

Comment: @Anahit DEV it can't do any harm. But Google will ignore it.

Comment: Thank you very much @James Jones for the answer!